# Firefox Video tag failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

i got a problem when use html5 video tag

I created a sample aspnet mvc project , on a page (named Index), i test video tag

```
@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<video  autoplay="true" controls="controls"  type="video/mp4" id="vd" >  
    <source src="/Content/Video/oceans-mini.mp4"></source>
 Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.  
</video>
```

start debugging this project , it only work in Safari and Chrome, IE and firefox got dump with a gray rectangle and a "X" sign inside ...

after using firebug to check net request/response, i got this

```
[Response]
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2011 04:35:46 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Content-Range: bytes 0-4484952/4484953
Etag: "1CC78E2DCD83280"
Cache-Control: public
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 4484953
Connection: Close
```

why the connection is "close" , is there any config needs in my project

here my web config/webserver section , remain are default

```
<system.webServer>
   <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   <staticContent>
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
   </staticContent>

 </system.webServer>
```

appreciate any suggest

Comment: now [nuget package available for HTML5 Audio & Video, Please check this link](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MVC4.Video/)

Answer (score 0):

firefox doesn't understand proprietary formats like mp4. you should use separate video formats and put them in source elements like so

<video controls>
<source src="foo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<source src="foo.mp4" type="video/mp4">

you can generate different formats online via media.io

Comment: yeah,i have thought like you,but can u explain why it work : http://videos-cdn.mozilla.net/serv/marketing/firefox4/FF4_Jess3Features_VO_1.mp4

Comment: @albert "formats like mp4" what kind of formats are those? thanks

Comment: proprietary formats are formats made to only work with certain technologies in mind. .mp4 is owned by apple, .wma is owned by windows, etc. you can read all about it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_format they're closed and you have to play by their rules to use them. .mp3 is an open format, and will play on virtually anything. my answer is correct for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Apple uses mp4 while firefox and ie use .ogg/.ogv. OGG was the standard but, Apple refused to use it that is why there are two now.

```
<video  autoplay controls>      
<source src="/Content/Video/oceans-mini.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="/Content/Video/oceans-mini.ogv" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.   
</video>
```